# Use ansible to conditionally create a file if it does not already exist

Tags: ansible

I am using `ansible-runner` to run this ansible playbook; the playbook that creates a file, but I only want to create the file if it does not already exist on the server.

This playbook always runs the command.  How should I modify my command or playbook to only run the command if the file does not exist?

This is my playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Add a new file
  hosts: bobcat.att.net
  tasks:
    - name: Conditionally create a file
      shell: echo "insert-private-data" > $HOME/data.txt
```

Comment: Please note that the existing answer and the first given duplicate are not a good practice to answer your current problem. See the `copy` module and check the `content` and `force` option (as proposed in the latest registered duplicate).

Comment: @Zeitounator if you are going to redefine the duplicate, at least dup it to an answer that uses the `content` option.

Comment: I don't feel using `content` in place of `src` as can be found in the documentation example linked in the duplicate is sufficiently different to need duplicate answer (else I would have answered).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `shell` module, you should use the `args` / `creates` syntax to conditionally create the file...

Example:

```yaml
---
- name: Add a new file
  hosts: bobcat.att.net
  tasks:
    - name: Conditionally create a file
      shell: echo "insert-sensitive-data" > $HOME/data.txt
      args:
        creates: "$HOME/data.txt"
```

That said, if you want full control over the specific file attributes of the file, you can use the ansible `copy` module with `force: no`:

```yaml
---
- name: Add a new file
  hosts: bobcat.att.net
  tasks:
    - name: Conditionally create a file if it does not exist
      copy:
        content: "insert-sensitive-data"
        dest: "{{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}/data.txt"
        force: no
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0400
      become: true
      become_with: sudo
      become_user: root
```

Comment: Regarding "_What part of `shell` with `args:` `creates:` is not idempotent?_", in example if the file already exists with incorrect content. Whereby a `copy` task will make sure it exists with the correct content a `shell` tasks will not. And that's what the Use Case is about, to create a file in the Desired State (incl. content), if it is not existing. But one would need to use `force: true`.